# Inserting temp table values into a table.

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a temp table declared

```
declare @tmptable( 
      value nvarchar(500) not null 
      );
```

I use a function to insert values into that temp table. 
I am trying to figure out how to update a table using the values of @tmptable

```
  insert into t1 (
   active
   ,SchoolId
   ,inserted
   )
   select 
   1
   ,temp.value
   ,@insertedDate   
   select temp.value from @tmptable;
```

When i try to insert in table t1 it doesn't work. I guess there are two Select statements is causing the problem. Please let me know how to fix it. Thanks

Comment: You state that you are trying to "update a table", but I do not see an `UPDATE` statement. Are you trying to `INSERT` new records or perform an `UPDATE`?

Comment: what is `temp` in `temp.value`, there is no alias used ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO t1
  (
    ACTIVE
   ,SchoolId
   ,INSERTED
  )
SELECT 1
      ,temp.value
      ,@insertedDate
FROM   @tmptable temp;
```

Comment: The second statement will not work cause if @tempTable has more than one record will be problem the subquery.

Comment: Thanks but I thought he has single value, and the first solution also hints on the single value coz he as hardcoded values there

Comment: You r welcome. The first will play with any amount of values and is the right way i think. :)

Comment: @ I am unable to figure out temp.value? If anyone suggest.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one -

```
INSERT INTO dbo.t1
(
      Active
    , SchoolId
    , Inserted
)
SELECT 
      1
    , t.value
    , @insertedDate
FROM @tmptable t;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into t1 (
 active
,SchoolId
,inserted
)
select 
1
,temp.value
,@insertedDate   
from @tmptable;
```

this will work...